# Join two models and concatenate in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have two models, mpa and Cid - (only displaying relevant data)

```
class Mpa(models.Model):
    mpa_number = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    legacy_mpa = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    rbc_transit_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Cid(models.Model):
    mpa = models.ForeignKey(Mpa,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    anchor_cid = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    campaign_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    google_cid = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have joined two tables on foreign key, using **select_related**:

```
result = Cid.objects.all().select_related('mpa')
```

mpa_number has one to many relation with anchor_cid. 
I wanted to display all anchor_cid, that corresponds to an mpa_number, in one row (there is a table in template).
For concatenating anchor_cid, I have used **Concat** like this -

```
query_set = result.values('mpa_id').annotate(name = Concat('anchor_cid'))
```

Since `.values()` returns a dictionary and `.all()` returns a model instance. I can't figure out a way of joining them together and displaying them in template.
I have tried searching for a solution but couldn't find this scenario.
Maybe I'm trying to do this in wrong way and somebody can point me in right direction..
(using Django 2.1.5 and mysql database)

Comment: You said "Anchor_cid has one to many relation with mpa_number", but your models (and the rest of your question) show the opposite relationship: mpa_number has one to many relationship with anchor_cid.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to do the logic in your `models.py` or `views.py` instead. For example:

```
#models.py

class Mpa(models.Model):
    mpa_number = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    legacy_mpa = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    rbc_transit_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def related_cids(self):
        #get a list of values
        anchors = self.cid_set.all().values_list('cid_anchor', flat=True)

        #get set of unique results and convert back to list
        unique_anchors = set(anchors)
        anchor_list = list(unique_anchors)

        #concatenate list values into a long string, separated by
        #single spaces, and return
        return ' '.join(anchor_list)
```

Here, `cid_set` is the default [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), which allows the `Mpa` instance to locate all related `Cid` instances. [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) only retrieves the actual `cid_anchor` values, as a simple list.

In your template, you should then be able to do:

```
{{ mpa_object.related_cids }}
```

Comment: It works like a charm! @ZG101 However it is returning duplicates. Is it possible to select distinct? I tried this - 
```self.cid_set.all().values_list('anchor_cid', flat=True).distinct()```
but it didn't work.

Comment: I've updated the answer to remove duplicates in Python, which is fine as long as your lists aren't huge (which I assume is the case if you're displaying the whole thing in a table). `distinct` will normally only filter out identical rows. You can filter out identical columns only in PostgreSQL, but there are [caveats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) when combining with `values`, so I think this approach is better for your case.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this before. I'm using mysql database (updated question) and I'm not sure if 'set' works fine with that. I'm still getting same data when printing anchor_list.

Comment: `set` removes duplicates in Python, so it doesn't matter which database you're using. It will always work. One possibility is that the strings are not perfectly identical (e.g. "abc  " vs "abc"). If they are identical, make sure you have updated the final line to return `' '.join(anchor_list)`, and not just `' '.join(anchors)`.

Comment: Hey ZG101, I didn't tried the last solution as it was impacting overall performance of application. As you guessed it earlier, lists aren't huge at the moment but its growing fast. I have rather created a sql view and created a new model with `migration= False` and using this for displaying data in template.